# Trying to keep buttons from moving when resizing window

Tags: html, css, css-position

***Before Resize***
[image: Website when full screen]

***After Resize***
[image: Website when shrinking down]

Hello, I'm trying to find a solution to solve my buttons moving out of place when resizing my window with just HTML and CSS preferably.
Would I have to apply media queries for every size to keep it the same or is there a more straightforward solution?

Below is my code, please help, thank you!

***HTML***

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Nazareth</h1>
    <div class="headerButtons">
        <p>About me</p>
        <p>My Projects</p>
        <p>Contact Me</p>
    </div>

</header>

<div id="tv">
    <img src="stuff/pngwing.com.png" alt="">
    <div id="tvButtons">
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

***CSS***

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: var(--white-color);

}
/*=============NAVBAR=====================*/
header > h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 2rem;
    color: var(--blue-color);
    font-size: 3rem;

}
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--brown-color);
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
.headerButtons {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
header p {

    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 2px solid #847728;

}
header p:hover {
    background-color: var(--orange-color);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/*=================END OF NAVBAR=====================*/

#tv {

    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}
#tvButtons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    right: 469px;
    top: 235px;
}
#tvButtons button{
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

#tvButtons button:active{
    background-color: #ffe95b;
}
```

Comment: what is the width of the tv? Is it centered on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. 
Change this:

```
#tvButtons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    right: 469px;
    top: 235px;
}
```

to

```
#tvButtons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(1470%);
}
```

If it doesn't work as expected, change the % of the translateX value.

Comment: I agree with this answer and approach `top`, `left` (instead of `right`) and `transform` CSS properties (it makes sense + should be doing the work in most cases), but shouldn't this be ideally solved with `media queries`?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that using `media queries` to handle this is a solution. It won't work as expected.

Comment: @str1ng  Media Queries apply styles at _breakpoints_ (fixed sizes), but the OP wants a solution for _any size_.

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked! I thought that the transform propert was mostly used for animation.

Comment: Would you upvote my answer if it's useful for you? thanks.